# How to reach local files with an ajax call in phonegap?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, cordova, sencha-touch

i Have this piece of code for load a json file stored in the same directory of phonegap ( iPhone ) project ( usually in the "www" folder ), how can i reach "routes.json" ?. My project have this tree folder:

__www/

_*_*_index.html

_*_*_index.json ( where is located this code )

_*_*_routes.json*

```
  store: new Ext.data.Store({
                    model  : 'routes',
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                                  url : 'file://??????/www/routes.json',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json'
                         }
                    },
                    autoLoad: true
                })
```

Comment: You should be able to use 'url: routes.json' - If the json file is in the same folder as your main Javascript file.

Comment: It was the first thing that i have tried, without results.In fact the app show always the Loading spinner without loading anything...

Comment: Could you post a part of your JSON file?

Comment: This is the json file:
[
  {
   "nome":"Borgo e Centro",
   "lunghezza":"2 Km",
   "durata":"1,5 ore",
   "id":"1"
  },
  {
   "nome":"Commerciale",
   "lunghezza":"2 Km",
   "durata":"1,5 ore",
   "id":"2"
  },
  {
   "nome":"Parchi",
   "lunghezza":"2 Km",
   "durata":"1,5 ore",
   "id":"2"
  }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is a bug in the Sencha Touch Ext.data.Proxy implementation.  I spent a couple hours trying to get this work and was unsuccessful.  It took me less than 5 minutes to implement it using jQuery.

```
//Initialize the Store
new Ext.data.Store(
  { 
    model: "Routes", 
    storeId: "Routes",
    //The Proxy isn't used but it is a required configuration option
    proxy: {
      type: 'ajax' 
    }
});

//Populate the store using jQuery.get()
$.get('routes.json',
      function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        if(status == "success") {
          var store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('Routes');
          store.loadData(data);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

Treat PhoneGap's **www** directory like you would a directory on your server. You can create as many sub-folders as you like, and you would reference files with relative links.

As YDL mentioned, if you're trying to access *index.json* and it resides at the root level of the **www** folder, you would use: `index.json`. As another example, if you had a sub-folder called **data** that housed all your json files, you would use: `data/index.json`.

Comment: But i haven't a server in a phonegap app. So it needs absolute paths...Though... Is the same behaviour when you open an html file on your PC, in fact in the address bar the full path is displayed.

Comment: You are correct that when you open an HTML file on your PC, the address bar displays the full path of the file location. However, you can still have relative links/paths in your HTML file, and they will still work properly. The same is true with the PhoneGap **www** folder. You should be using relative paths, not absolute, in your PG project.

Comment: I have tried this with same results....i also tried "./routes.json".....but nothing... I though that relative paths work only in html files...