# Find out what exactly XMLHttpRequest is requesting

Tags: ajax, windows-phone-7, cordova

We're developing a cross-platform application using PhoneGap. At one point, it makes an AJAX request to a relative path, which works fine on both Android and iOS, but not Windows Phone - it gets a 404 response. An absolute URL works fine. The following code:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', 'personalData.html');
console.log(a.href);
```

also resolves to the correct absolute URL. However, the following:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "personalData.html", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
};
```

returns 404. I want to find out what's going on. Is there any way to know what absolute path XHR is requesting?

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is unbeatable. It will tell you exactly what the request is doing.

It also [works with the Windows Phone emulator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx). To debug an actual device, setup FIddler to accept external connections and assign Fiddler as a proxy on the phone.
I have done both  scenarios, works fine.

Give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's all happening inside the emulator/phone so the requests never reach Fiddler.

Comment: False assumption from your side. I would argue that this still should be possible, I have done it myself several times. See my updated answer.

Comment: It captures requests to external resources fine. But my problem happens when requesting a local html file, such as /app/www/pages/home.html. Fiddler doesn't see those.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand, then take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224954/how-to-reach-local-files-with-an-ajax-call-in-phonegap   and  this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562274/trouble-in-ajax-call-for-local-files

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest is a JavaScript object that was designed by Microsoft and adopted by Mozilla, Apple, and Google, it's not related to Phonegap.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest

Said this, you could try using an http Proxy like Fiddler to view all http trafic.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have try your code in my project (Phonegap/WinPhone7) and your code didn't get anything till I initialized the request (`xhr.send();`).

I have no idea how you make request without this method.